# How can we allow unpublish to fail on need?

Tags: 2011, templating

I have a situation where i need to stop unpublishing of specific pages.
I want to write some template or code which will stop unpublishing for such pages.

The need is very intresting .

- I have a page text.xml in CMS , i publish it and it goes to broker as well as on file system as text.xml .
- I renamed it to text1.xml .
- I created a new page text.xml and publish it again . This also will go to broker as a new entry and will go to file system as text.xml.
- If i publish/unpublish the old text1.xml , it removes the text.xml from file system.
- I need to stop old unpublish to remove it from file system so i want unpublish to fail for this particular page .

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify it a bit more, what exactly do you need to do and perhaps also add the why?

Comment: Do you get the same behavior if you change the order of those steps? For example, wouldn't publishing text1.xml after the rename remove this dependency?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question completely, but depending on the purpose you can:

- Configure Event System to fail UnpublishTransaction when you send something to be unpublished
- Configure Event System to fail when setting item published state (basically during marking item as unpublished)
- Configure custom resolver to fail when resolving at the very early stage of unpublishing

Rendering doesn't occur during unpublish, so you can't do anything in template

Comment: :Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking .